# Get the results of a pytest run from within code when calling `pytest.main()`?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to do some work with the results of a pytest run after running my test suite.

Currently I wrap pytest with a script called `run_test_battery.py` that calls `pytest.main(args=args)`.

Is there a way to get the test results from outside pytest like this? Or do I have to use hooks like `pytest_runtest_makereport` or `pytest_runtest_logreport`?

Currently I'm using xdist for parallelization and turns out there are complications with that and some hooks: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/79

The result of this complication means I seem to have to log test results to a file in a hook and then read them in from the calling script. Can you get access to the session after running the test suite? That would simplify a lot.